# How to get a sample of random numbers in golang?

Tags: go, random, slice, sample

Or I have to use straightforward way like:

```
var arr []int

for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    arr = append(arr, rand.Intn(100))
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your approach?

Comment: @Flimzy Maybe there is an elegant way to do wit standard library package?

Comment: What you have looks pretty elegant to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you did is clean and fast enough. What you could improve on it is to pre-allocate the slice and fill it using a `for.. range` loop like this:

```
s := make([]int, 5)
for i := range s {
    s[i] = rand.Intn(100)
}
```

The `math/rand` package also has a [`rand.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Read) function which fills a slice with random bytes. So if you want to fill a `[]byte` slice with random data, this is all it takes:

```
s := make([]byte, 100)
rand.Read(s) // This never returns an error
```

Another interesting way would be to take advantage of [`rand.Rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand) being an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). Which means it has a `Read()` method which fills a `[]byte` with random data.

This combined with the [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package, you can "fill" variables with random data. Create and pass a `rand.Rand` to the [`binary.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) function as the source, and that's it.

This is how it would look like:

```
r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))

s := make([]int32, 5)
err := binary.Read(r, binary.BigEndian, &s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(s)
```

Output:

```
[203443513 1611652563 -235795288 8294855 -802604260]
```

This is "cool" enough to even fill structs for example:

```
var point struct{ X, Y int16 }
err = binary.Read(r, binary.BigEndian, &point)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v", point)
```

Output:

```
{X:-15471 Y:2619}
```

Try these examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/96bW2Tso5jQ).

One handicap of using `binary.Read()` is that–understandably–it can only fill values of fixed-size types, and the most famous exception is the common `int` type, whose size is not fixed (architecture dependent). So you can't fill an `[]int` slice or a struct with a field of `int` type. That's why I used `int32` and `int16` types in the above examples.

Of course in these solutions you could not limit the range of random numbers that are used to fill your variables. For that, the initial loop is still easier.